# NodeJS exec function does not run the Java class/bash script completely

Tags: node.js

I am trying to call a bashscript from my nodejs function everytime the condition is true. The bash script then executes a Java class file.

I am experiencing the following problem

1. Code works fine
2. NodeJs function does call the bashscript
3. the bash script also execute the Java class file
4. However, i think it does not finish execution Because the first line of java code  is to create a lock file and after execution is complete delete the lock file. but it will only create the lock file and the program never outputs anything after that.

The below nodeJS method is triggered every 60 seconds. The Java class file takes about 80 seconds to complete So is it true that when the second time this method is called it will kill the process ran before that ? I want to keep it async but at the same time let the exec method to complete ?  I tried calling the nodejs method every 120 second and this would make it all work fine but i can't afford to change the interval from 60 seconds to 120.

runbash.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
CP=/home/sanity/Data/free  # The classpath to use
java -cp $CP JavaClassFile $1 $2 $3
```

nodejs function

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

var checkDataMonitor = function(t,body,url,username,password) {

    var m = "checkDataMonitor";

    var servicestatus = body.serviceStatus["Data [free]"].available;

    if ("true" == servicestatus.toString()) { 

    var command="bash /home/sanity/Data/free/runbash.sh "+url+" "+username+" "+password;
    child = exec(command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout);
    sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
   });
    throw new Error("serviceStatus.Data [free].available is true. serviceStatus.Data [free].available: " + util.inspect(servicestatus)); 
    }

    clog(t,m,"Exit. Success.");
}
```

Comment: Inorder to pass arguments to the bash script, you have to give the arguments as an array to exec function exec(path,[url,username,password],function(){})

Comment: I don't think passing the argument is a problem since it does work they i have placed it.